# How to fix Error "A conflict exists with definition * in namespace public." using ASC2.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, overriding, public

In a class hierarchy where:

**MngLayers** extends **Manager_Panel**, which extends **Manager_Base**...

-- In **Manager_Base**, I've defined an `init()` method:

```
public class Manager_Base {
    //....

    public function init():void {
        //Do initialization here...
    }
}
```

-- In **Manager_Panel**, I do NOT override the `init()` method.

-- In **MngLayers**, I override the `init()` method.

```
public override function init():void {
    super.init();
    //Do custom initialization here...  
}
```

When I attempt to compile this, I get this unhelpful compilation error:

> **Error: A conflict exists with definition init in namespace public.**

I'm not sure this matters, but I'm using the **ASC2.0** compiler (from the AIR SDK 3.7) with **-inline** support.

Is there something broken in the compiler that prevents it from doing simple method-overriding compilation like the previous compiler could?

Answer (score 0):

AH! Damn, well it's just the ASC2.0 not being descriptive enough!

My bad, I had a **duplicate** `init()` overriden method in the leaf sub-class (MngLayers) all this time. It would of helped if the compiler pointed out that duplicate one instead!

Hope this helps anyone else making the same rookie mistake! :D

Comment: The error is actually extremely descriptive. You had conflicting function names using "init" that were using the "public" namespace.

Comment: Nope, cuz it didn't point out the line number to any (or both) of the method declarations conflicting.